# launch application from osx terminal in 32bit mode

Tags: macos, 64-bit, terminal, 32-bit, terminal.app

How can I pass an argument to the "open" command to launch an application from the terminal in 32-bit mode?

```
open /path/to/some.app [--args arguments]
```

I have to manually check and uncheck the '32-bit mode' from the finder's info panel everytime: it's really annoying.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any way to do it with `open`, but you can do it by using `arch` to run the binary within the application's bundle:

```
arch -arch i386 /path/to/appname.app/Contents/MacOS/appname &
```

(if you leave off the &, the shell will wait for the app to exit before letting you continue.)